# Get ClassLoader from gradle org.gradle.api.Project?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm writing a [gradle plugin](https://github.com/HendraAnggrian/r-sync) that wishes to read specific properties file from resources of a project of which this plugin is applied to. To read those resources, I need a classpath of the project. Currently I'm going with:

```
org.gradle.api.Project.getBuildscript().getClassLoader().getResourcesAsStream(...)
```

But it always returns null even though such resource exists in that project.

Comment: try adding the resource to the `buildSrc` classpath

Answer (score 0):

Gradle buildscript is comilped and put into a local cache, so the project is not on the classpath of buildscript classloader. What you need is probably `org.gradle.api.Project. absoluteProjectPath()`.

e.g. To read "src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF":

```
try(Reader in = new FileReader(project.absoluteProjectPath( "src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" ))) {
    //...
}
```